# code coverage for asp.net running on IIS(manual test)

Tags: c#, testing, code-coverage, manual

I require a tool that can do the following:

For an Asp.Net application deployed on IIS server (win2008R2, IIS7.5), when I click a web page on a client it can figur out which code is executed on the server, and which code is not executed

Is there a tool that can do this?

I have tried the following :

1. [OpenCover](https://github.com/OpenCover/opencover): This needs to be deployed to the IIS on the same machine the site is running on
2. [DotCover](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/): Unable secondary development

Comment: This question is very unclear. Please clarify or re-phrase.

Comment: Not AFAIK - most coverage tools need to either instrument the code before execution or during execution (e.g. OpenCover) either way they need access to the running code to gather their results before at least passing them on to a 3rd party for collection and analysis. If you are thinking of putting any coverage tool on a production box then I would advise against it due to the performance impact.